# Why would Linux boot from a USB drive but not a hard drive?

Tags: boot, uefi, boot-loader, bios, buildroot

I have a x86_64 Linux Kernel, with EFI_STUB enabled, and packaged into a EFI System Partition that I compiled using Buildroot.  It generally will boot on any machine by just dd'ing it to a device and booting from it but on some machines with particular BIOS versions it only boots from USB drives but when I try to boot it from a SATA SSD it just shows a blank screen with a blinking cursor.  Upgrading the BIOS to a newer version fixes the issue.

What would cause booting from USB to work fine but booting from SATA disk to not work?  I'm at a loss for how to debug this because it is so early in the boot process.  While upgrading the bios solves the issue there are some machines I need this to work on where there aren't any bios updates available so I'm wondering if there are changes I can make in my kernel configuration to get around this problem.

Comment: So, you can't exactly say how it fails and you're asking why? Not sure it's humanly possible to answer the question.

Comment: For some BIOS versions you need to explicitly enable EFI. The default is off. Also some older versions of BIOS will not support EFI at all.

Comment: External drives actually boot from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. Internal drives typically boot from /EFI/xxxx where xxxx is distribution folder in ESP - efi system partition. Not sure how efi stub then works. Most newer UEFI should also support fallback or drive boot from internal drive which is the same as external or /EFI/boot /bootx64.efi and shown in UEFI just as a drive.

Comment: The BIOS in question support EFI booting and the kernel is located at /EFI/boot/bootx64.efi on the drive.  I believe it is finding the .efi file correctly because I can see it in the boot menu.